# how to boost Lucene facets?

Tags: lucene, faceted-search, facet

Is there a way to add a boosting factor to a facet in Lucene? Something like:

```
List<CategoryPath> facetCategories = new ArrayList<CategoryPath>();
for (MyFeature f : allFeatures) {
    **Double boost = f.getBoost();** 
    facetCategories.add(new CategoryPath("feature", f.getName(), **bost**));
}
CategoryDocumentBuilder categoryDocBuilder = new CategoryDocumentBuilder(taxonomy);
categoryDocBuilder.setCategoryPaths(facetCategories);
```

Comment: I do not know why facet query need boost. Facet query just return document number while the boost affect sort order in documents result.

Comment: thanks @pensz, we are using Facets in a non-conventional way: facets are semantic concepts, and we query for similar concepts. That's why we wanted to be able to boost them.

Comment: so, why not use normal boost query multi times rather than facet query?